# change label text using if statements - obj c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have some UILabels and buttons. This is my code:

```
    if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"The three blue dots represents GPS towers. Click Go to advance"])
    {
        firstClick = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome!"
                                                message:@"Blah, blah blah"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [firstClick show];

        distanceLabel.text = @"Distance to first tower: 50 km";
        a = YES;
    }

    if (a)
    {
        label.text = @"Now you know that the distance to the first tower is 50 km. Click Go to advance";
    }
```

All this is inside an action method for a button. when the button is pressed the alertview views and the distanceLabel changes its text. Then the OK button on the alert is clicked I would like to change the label.text. I have tried with an instance boolean but that doesnt work.
Why wont that work and what do I have to do instead??

Comment: Check to make sure your label is not nil and is properly connected inside your storyboard/nib.

Comment: in those cases, breakpoint, step and check for nil and anyway you should get what is wrong.

Comment: How do i check for nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like an action to occur when an alert view button is pressed, you should implement the protocol method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSLog(@"button clicked at index %d", buttonIndex);
    NSLog(@"about to update a label.  this won't work if it's nil... %@", label);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user clicked button %d", buttonIndex"];
}
```

Comment: how do I use this for checking if the button is clicked in the alertview?

Comment: it will be invoked only when a button is clicked